# jQuery .on method - undefined is not a function

Tags: jquery, undefined

I cannot get .on() method to work on dynamic elements. Tried so many different attempts but nothing worked. Can somebody point me out what I am doing wrong?

```
$(document.body).on('change', 'select', function() {
    alert('hello');
});
```

In my html, to which the above script is attached, I have a couple of select elements. On change event of one of the elements, the following error is displayed in the browser's console:

Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function  .. (inside jQuery script file)

Any suggestions to solve this? Thanks!

----- Update -----

Sorry for the brief explanation. jQuery version is 1.11.1.

HTML:

```
<div id="ticket-container">
    <div id="ticket1">
    <label for="ticket1">Ticket: </label>                        
    <select class="ticket-list" id="ticket1" name="ticket1">
        <option value="1">ticket 1</option>
        <option value="5">ticket 2</option>
        <option value="6">Ticket 3</option>
    </select>                        
    <label for="tickettype1">Ticket type: </label>                        
    <select class="tickettype-list" id="tickettype1" name="tickettype1">
        <option value="1">Child</option>
        <option value="2">Adult</option>
        <option value="3">Elderly</option>
    </select>                        
    <label for="quantity1">Quantity: </label>                        
    <input name="quantity1" type="text" value="1" id="quantity1">                                            
    </div>
</div>
```

In addition, the above html is generated through Laravel - but this shouldn't effect jQuery.

Also, I have an Add button which on click will append the second div with ID 'ticket1' after itself, and incrementing each ID (ex: ticket2) on each click.

This is why I need to use .on() jQuery method as I need to bind change event to select element with class 'ticket-list'.

Comment: anyone? any help? still cannot solve it.

Comment: seems to be fine http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/N2ETT/1/

Comment: what are the other script files used in the page

Comment: also instead of `$(document.body)` try `jQuery(document.body)`

Comment: I had a similar issue, using jQuery 2.1.3 and it claiming that .on was not a function. I found that this was cause by a different older script used in this particular page. What was interesting is it would use .on with no problems up until a specific point, than it was magically not a function during the same loop. The "older script" in question was Spry, thanks @ArunPJohny for the simple fix, not using $ as an alias to jQuery

Answer (score 1):

This can happen if you include a 3rd party library which includes its own bundled version of jQuery.  jQuery Tools is a prime suspect.  You think you are running jQuery 1.11 but jQuery tools is internally using 1.6 or some ancient thing.  So it starts spitting out errors about "on" being undefined.

Comment: an old jQuery 1.5 version was breaking things on our old clunker of an app. Thanks

Answer (score -1):

I can't exactly tell what you are doing wrong, cause I don't know which `jQuery` version you are using or how your html looks like
see working: http://jsfiddle.net/HbaSB

Comment: Thanks but the problem is still not solved. I've included my html for a better description of the problem. Thank you for your time.